# Why do I get "Editor could not be initialized" error while running UIMA Ruta scripts?

Tags: uima, ruta

I often get errors like this while running UIMA Ruta scripts. Why so ? What can I do to prevent it ?

Does it depend on my code or is it related to Eclipse IDE ?

**Error:**

Editor could not be initialized.

```
org.apache.uima.UIMARuntimeException
at org.apache.uima.util.CasIOUtils.load(CasIOUtils.java:368)
at org.apache.uima.util.CasIOUtils.load(CasIOUtils.java:312)
at org.apache.uima.util.CasIOUtils.load(CasIOUtils.java:193)
at org.apache.uima.util.CasIOUtils.load(CasIOUtils.java:218)
at org.apache.uima.caseditor.editor.DocumentUimaImpl.setContent(DocumentUimaImpl.java:248)
at org.apache.uima.caseditor.editor.DocumentUimaImpl.<init>(DocumentUimaImpl.java:100)
at org.apache.uima.caseditor.ide.DefaultCasDocumentProvider.createDocument(DefaultCasDocumentProvider.java:405)
at org.apache.uima.caseditor.editor.TextDocumentProvider.createDocument(TextDocumentProvider.java:78)
at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractDocumentProvider.createElementInfo(AbstractDocumentProvider.java:333)
at org.apache.uima.caseditor.editor.TextDocumentProvider.createElementInfo(TextDocumentProvider.java:110)
at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractDocumentProvider.connect(AbstractDocumentProvider.java:400)
at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.doSetInput(AbstractTextEditor.java:4233)
at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.StatusTextEditor.doSetInput(StatusTextEditor.java:237)
at org.apache.uima.caseditor.editor.AnnotationEditor.doSetInput(AnnotationEditor.java:837)
at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor$19.run(AbstractTextEditor.java:3220)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:463)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:371)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow$14.run(WorkbenchWindow.java:2181)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.run(WorkbenchWindow.java:2177)
at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.internalInit(AbstractTextEditor.java:3238)
at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.init(AbstractTextEditor.java:3265)
at org.apache.uima.caseditor.editor.AnnotationEditor.init(AnnotationEditor.java:594)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.initialize(EditorReference.java:361)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.create(CompatibilityPart.java:319)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:898)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:879)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:121)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:345)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:264)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:162)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:104)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:73)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:55)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer.createWidget(ContributedPartRenderer.java:129)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:971)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:640)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:746)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:717)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:711)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:695)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl$1.handleEvent(PartServiceImpl.java:99)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler$1.run(UIEventHandler.java:40)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:186)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3108)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3098)
at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:541)
at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:500)
at org.eclipse.dltk.internal.ui.editor.EditorUtility.openInEditor(EditorUtility.java:399)
at org.eclipse.dltk.internal.ui.editor.EditorUtility.openInEditor(EditorUtility.java:157)
at org.eclipse.dltk.internal.ui.actions.OpenActionUtil.open(OpenActionUtil.java:45)
```

...............
org.apache.uima.util.XmlCasDeserializer.deserializeR(XmlCasDeserializer.java:110)
    at org.apache.uima.util.CasIOUtils.load(CasIOUtils.java:366)
    ... 125 more

Comment: Can you add the complete stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

This is an open problem in UIMA 2.9.0 and UIMA Ruta 2.5.0 and not solved yet. (If I interpret the exception correctly)

Right now, you need to remain with the XMI serialization format:

[image: XMI serial format in UIMA Ruta]

Comment: Oh.. ok,, but XMI (xmi) serialization is selected by default and still I face the same issue very often. Anyways Thanks !

Comment: Ah ok, I just thought because your stacktrace says something about XmlCasDeserializer, not Xmi...