# UIMA Ruta: Editor could not be initialized

Tags: uima, ruta

I am new to UIMA Ruta and I am currently trying to get a simple HelloWorld script to run.
I followed the instructions [here](https://help.averbis.com/confluence/display/AKB/Apache+UIMA+Ruta+Tutorial#ApacheUIMARutaTutorial-GettingStarted) to set up my HelloWorld project.

The first error that occured was `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/event/Logger` which I resolved by converting my project to a maven project and adding the `slf4j-api 2.0.0-alpha1` and `ruta-core 2.7.0` dependencies to pom.xml.

Now, my HelloWorld script generates an output file to the output folder. But when I try to open it with the UIMA Annotation Editor it says "Editor could not be initialized." with the following details:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.uima.cas.impl.CASImpl.createFsFromGenerator(CASImpl.java:1461)
at org.apache.uima.cas.impl.CASImpl.createFSAnnotCheck(CASImpl.java:1413)
at org.apache.uima.cas.impl.CASImpl.createFS(CASImpl.java:1394)
at org.apache.uima.cas.impl.XmiCasDeserializer$XmiCasDeserializerHandler.readFS(XmiCasDeserializer.java:599)
at org.apache.uima.cas.impl.XmiCasDeserializer$XmiCasDeserializerHandler.processDeferredFSs(XmiCasDeserializer.java:2042)
at org.apache.uima.cas.impl.XmiCasDeserializer$XmiCasDeserializerHandler.readFS(XmiCasDeserializer.java:503)
at org.apache.uima.cas.impl.XmiCasDeserializer$XmiCasDeserializerHandler.startElement(XmiCasDeserializer.java:435)
at org.apache.uima.util.XmlCasDeserializer$XmlCasDeserializerHandler.startElement(XmlCasDeserializer.java:148)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.uima.util.XmlCasDeserializer.deserializeR(XmlCasDeserializer.java:109)
at org.apache.uima.util.CasIOUtils.load(CasIOUtils.java:368)
at org.apache.uima.util.CasIOUtils.load(CasIOUtils.java:313)
at org.apache.uima.util.CasIOUtils.load(CasIOUtils.java:194)
at org.apache.uima.util.CasIOUtils.load(CasIOUtils.java:219)
at org.apache.uima.caseditor.editor.DocumentUimaImpl.setContent(DocumentUimaImpl.java:291)
at org.apache.uima.caseditor.editor.DocumentUimaImpl.<init>(DocumentUimaImpl.java:105)
at org.apache.uima.caseditor.ide.DefaultCasDocumentProvider.createDocument(DefaultCasDocumentProvider.java:400)
at org.apache.uima.caseditor.editor.TextDocumentProvider.createDocument(TextDocumentProvider.java:103)
at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractDocumentProvider.createElementInfo(AbstractDocumentProvider.java:330)
at org.apache.uima.caseditor.editor.TextDocumentProvider.createElementInfo(TextDocumentProvider.java:135)
at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractDocumentProvider.connect(AbstractDocumentProvider.java:395)
at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.doSetInput(AbstractTextEditor.java:4187)
at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.StatusTextEditor.doSetInput(StatusTextEditor.java:260)
at org.apache.uima.caseditor.editor.AnnotationEditor.doSetInput(AnnotationEditor.java:924)
at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.lambda$1(AbstractTextEditor.java:3154)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:438)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:354)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.lambda$5(WorkbenchWindow.java:2364)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:72)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.run(WorkbenchWindow.java:2362)
at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.internalInit(AbstractTextEditor.java:3171)
at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.init(AbstractTextEditor.java:3196)
at org.apache.uima.caseditor.editor.AnnotationEditor.init(AnnotationEditor.java:667)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.initialize(EditorReference.java:354)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.create(CompatibilityPart.java:340)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:58)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:1001)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:966)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalInject(InjectorImpl.java:139)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:411)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:333)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:202)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:91)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:60)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:42)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer.createWidget(ContributedPartRenderer.java:132)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:1015)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:675)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:781)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:752)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:746)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:730)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl$1.handleEvent(PartServiceImpl.java:107)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.lambda$0(UIEventHandler.java:38)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:236)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:146)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4580)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application$1.syncExec(E4Application.java:219)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.handleEvent(UIEventHandler.java:38)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerWrapper.handleEvent(EventHandlerWrapper.java:205)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:203)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:1)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:151)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.dispatchEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:132)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.sendEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:75)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent.sendEvent(EventComponent.java:44)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.send(EventBroker.java:55)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.UIEventPublisher.notifyChanged(UIEventPublisher.java:63)
at org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.BasicNotifierImpl.eNotify(BasicNotifierImpl.java:424)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.impl.ElementContainerImpl.setSelectedElementGen(ElementContainerImpl.java:170)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.impl.ElementContainerImpl.setSelectedElement(ElementContainerImpl.java:188)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.showElementInWindow(ModelServiceImpl.java:652)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.bringToTop(ModelServiceImpl.java:616)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.delegateBringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:791)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.bringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:404)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.showPart(PartServiceImpl.java:1240)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3209)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.lambda$9(WorkbenchPage.java:3114)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:72)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3112)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3083)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3074)
at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:570)
at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:525)
at org.eclipse.dltk.internal.ui.editor.EditorUtility.openInEditor(EditorUtility.java:380)
at org.eclipse.dltk.internal.ui.editor.EditorUtility.openInEditor(EditorUtility.java:149)
at org.eclipse.dltk.internal.ui.actions.OpenActionUtil.open(OpenActionUtil.java:45)
at org.eclipse.dltk.ui.actions.OpenAction.run(OpenAction.java:265)
at org.eclipse.dltk.ui.actions.OpenAction.run(OpenAction.java:246)
at org.eclipse.dltk.ui.actions.SelectionDispatchAction.dispatchRun(SelectionDispatchAction.java:282)
at org.eclipse.dltk.ui.actions.SelectionDispatchAction.run(SelectionDispatchAction.java:260)
at org.eclipse.dltk.internal.ui.scriptview.ScriptExplorerActionGroup.handleOpen(ScriptExplorerActionGroup.java:327)
at org.eclipse.dltk.internal.ui.scriptview.ScriptExplorerPart.lambda$2(ScriptExplorerPart.java:629)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$2.run(StructuredViewer.java:796)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil.lambda$0(JFaceUtil.java:47)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:176)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.fireOpen(StructuredViewer.java:793)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1108)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireOpenEvent(OpenStrategy.java:275)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$2(OpenStrategy.java:270)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(OpenStrategy.java:310)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4131)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1056)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3944)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3547)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1173)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1062)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:635)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:559)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:155)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:137)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:107)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:400)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:660)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:597)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1468)
```

The same thing happens when I try to open the ExampleProject in the example-projects folder of the UIMA Ruta project. I know about this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40605574/why-do-i-get-editor-could-not-be-initialized-error-while-running-uima-ruta-scr) but it didn't solve my problem.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment there is no UIMA Ruta Version compatible with UIMA v3. Try downgrading the UIMA Version to 2.10.4 (for instance). For more info please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42040885/org-apache-uima-cas-casruntimeexception-uima-ruta) question.

Comment: Thank you. This is also stated on the UIMA website: "You should only install one of either version 2 or version 3 Eclipse plugin tooling, into a single Eclipse installation." I had to install the UIMA SDK 2.10.2 manually because the Eclipse Update Tool didn't let me install it (like here: [link](https://uima.apache.org/d/uimaj-current/overview_and_setup.html#ugr.ovv.eclipse_setup)). It always wanted to install the Runtime version 3.

Comment: Version 2.10.4 didn't work for me because the Eclipse Update tool only let me install Runtime version 2.10.2. Apparently, the SDK 2.10.4 and the Runtime 2.10.2 don't work together.